# Android SimpleCursorAdapter for generating ListView

Tags: android

I am using ListView in android

My data is coming from database

I Have learned SimpleCursorAdapter and this is the code from official docs

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.person_name_and_number, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

All the thing i have understand successfully created the list view also but there is one doubt
what the **use of last argument 0 in the constructor** they have not explained. Please tell me what this last argument is doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listview from Cursor (without Loaders)

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(

```
    this,                // The Activity context
    R.layout.list_item,  // Points to the XML for a list item
    cursor,              // Cursor that contains the data to display
    dataColumns,         // Bind the data in column "text_column"...
    viewIDs              // ...to the TextView with id "R.id.text_view"

    );
```

Listview from Cursor (Using Loaders)

To Asynchronously load data to the Containers(Listview or Fragments) Loaders are best approach.

```
// Initialize the adapter. Note that we pass a "null" Cursor as the
// third argument. We will pass the adapter a Cursor only when the
// data has finished loading for the first time (i.e. when the
// LoaderManager delivers the data to onLoadFinished). Also note
// that we have passed the "0" flag as the last argument. This
// prevents the adapter from registering a ContentObserver for the
// Cursor (the CursorLoader will do this for us!).
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,
    null, dataColumns, viewIDs, 0);
```

The following URL describes above.
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html

Answer (score 1):

The [SimpleCursorAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29) explains that these are flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter:

> Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter, as per
>   CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int).

See [the CursorAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#CursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29) for more information.

Comment: that is what I am asking which type of behaviour please give me one example

Comment: Just read the documentation. It is explained there. I provided links for you. Do you want me to copy/paste it as well?

Comment: @Please tell me the menaing of this line

Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter; may be any combination of FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY and FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER.